# google sheets cell displays two colors

Tags: google-sheets, colors, cell, gradient

I want google sheets to display two colors within one cell. In Excel you can do this with VBA script. I can't figure out a script for google sheets that works. ChaptGPT hasn't given me the right answer either. Can someone help me with a code to display two colors within one cell, split diagonally?

Comment: My research has shown that this is not possible with Google Apps Script for Sheets at this time. However, there is an existing [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/225941025#comment5)  for this matter, where users are also requesting the same functionality. You can also cast your vote for this feature request, as the more votes it receives, the more likely it is to be implemented in the near future.